# Split Four Columns without Headers into Two Rows in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have data that looks like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Work Order Number | 12345678-123 | Total Fee | £1,000 |
| Work Order Title | A Project | Remaining Fee | £500 |
| Sector | Commercial | Last Review | 01/12/22 |

And I want to re-shape that data in Power Query so it looks like the table below (Although the order of the columns isn't important).

| Work Order Number | Work Order Title | Sector | Total Fee | Remaining Fee | Last Review |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678-123 | A Project | Commercial | £1,000 | £500 | 01/12/22 |

Does anybody have any pointers on how to do this?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
// assumes groups of three rows
     #"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 3), Int64.Type}}),
// assumes groups of 2 columns + index
     Part1 = Table.SelectColumns(#"Integer-Divided Column",{"Column1", "Column2", "Index"}),
     Part2a = Table.SelectColumns(#"Integer-Divided Column",{"Column3", "Column4", "Index"}),
Part2b = Table.RenameColumns(Part2a,{{"Column3", "Column1"}, {"Column4", "Column2"}}),
combined=Table.Combine({Part1,Part2b}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(combined, List.Distinct(combined[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Last Review", type date}, {"Total Fee", type number}, {"Remaining Fee", type number}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]